# How to sell coupon code in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise

How to sell a coupon code in Magento.

The coupon code that can be the gift to a friend, so that he can buy products with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like:

1. Create Discount Coupons Manually
2. Creating Virtual Products (They will be image files that contain your Discount Codes in a flashy design and blah blah )
3. Set a Category, or page that shows your Virtual Products. (Like 20% Discount Code )
4. When Customer purchases that coupon, they will be able to receive the Image file which actually has your discount code.
5. This can be distributed by customers to their friends and can be applied by them at checkout.